# Excel FILTER to return array non zero columns

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

I have an Excel table that has the following (plus more) data in it:

[image: Start data]

What I would like to do is filter the data to return all but the columns that have all 0 values in them, i.e. the return would be:

[image: Expected outcome]

I can't for the life of me get my filter expression to return what I want, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With BYCOL and LAMBDA:

```
=FILTER(B1:I4,BYCOL(B2:I4,LAMBDA(a,SUM(a)))>0)
```

Or as [@BigBen](/users/9245853) pointed out in [a comment](/posts/comments/126076518):

```
=FILTER(B1:I4,BYCOL(B2:I4,LAMBDA(a,OR(a)))
```

[image]

Since BYCOL and LAMBDA are not available to all office 365 users yet here is one that does not use it.

```
=FILTER(B1:I4,TRANSPOSE(MMULT(--((TRANSPOSE(B2:I4)<>0)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(B2:I4),,1,0))>0))
```

[image]

Comment: I can't test this currently, but what about `=FILTER(B1:I4,BYCOL(B2:I4,LAMBDA(a,OR(a)))`? Using `SUM` might only work if all values are nonnegative.